# Speeding up some computation on matrix in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I am writing my program which is very poorly optimized, so need to speed up the process. Reproducible example similar to my problem is like below,

```
x= seq(1,10000, by = 1000)
```

Function below, measures the time to compute the vectorized(?) operation on the matrix with given dimension row of x and column of 2.

```
testy = function(x){
testmatrix <- matrix(runif(x*2,0,10), nrow=x, ncol=2)
y=microbenchmark(rowSums(testmatrix),unit="ms",times=1)$time
return(y)
}
```

Function below, measures the time to compute the operation on the matrix using internal for loop from R

```
testy2 = function(x){
testmatrix <- matrix(runif(x*2,0,10), nrow=x, ncol=2)
y=microbenchmark(apply(testmatrix, 1, function(x) sum(x)), unit="ms", times=1)$time 
return(y)
}
```

Plotting the performance of the each function for increasing size of matrix gives dramatic difference in log scaled computation time.

```
plot(x, log(sapply(x,testy2))) # apply (internal for loop)
lines(x, log(sapply(x,testy))) # vectorized operation?
```

I suspect the problem in my program in efficiency is that I use "apply" version of computation on the given matrix. Then it means I need to compute this operation using somewhat vectorized version such as function testy.

My first question is

Is above difference in performance is indeed from

rowSums(x) vs apply(x, 1, sum) ?

In my program, the equivalent of the "summing" in above example, is so much more complex which involves numerical integration.

then to boost up my speed, 
then it means I have to write "rowSums" version of my code?

Thank you so much guys,

Comment: The help page for `rowSums` answers your questions.

Comment: The documentation for `rowSums` literally says "These functions are equivalent to use of apply with FUN = mean or FUN = sum with appropriate margins, but are a lot faster.", so yes, they are faster. If you want really faster numerical performance you may have to resort to Rcpp.